# JPQL query in joined tables

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpql

my question is very simple, though I found multiple solution, but I didn't succeed to implement them correctly, so I'm asking for your help.

in an Entity Class called `Prof` , I have this :

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer idUser;
    @OneToMany (cascade = PERSIST)
    @JoinTable(name="jnt_Prof_Exam",
                joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="idUser"), 
                inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="idExam"))
        private List<Exam> exams;
```

now I want to know how to get just the List of `Exam` for a given idUser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this JPQL,

```
SELECT p.exams FROM Prof p WHERE p.idUser = :id
```

The call would be something like this:

```
List<Exam> exams = em.createQuery("...JPQL...")
     .setParameter("id", idUser)
     .getSingleResult();
```

With this JPQL just going to get the List of `exams` and not all the objects in class `Prof`.

Even better, You can use that JPQL with NamedQuery, but with this you can test fast. :)

Comment: thank you so much, I have just one more question, if I want to update the List<Exam> , I mean I want to add one item to the attribute 'exams' for a given idUser, can u help me in this? :)

Comment: I recommend you create the new exam object and persist it with em.persist(exam) and, if it's your use case, make this jpa query after the persist.

Comment: but if I persist the exam object, it will be addes only in the exam table, in other word there will be no link between the exam and the prof, I mean nothing will be added in the joined table.

Comment: Once you do again the query to get the exams, you going to have all the exams information. I don't know you use case, maybe, if I know it better I could help you more.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the **em.find()** like this :

```
EntityManager em;
List<Exam> exams= new ArrayList<>( em.find( Prof.class, givenID ).getExams() );
```

Comment: Yes, this is truth, but the `find()` method going to make more than one query, it going to fill an object `Prof` and then will do the regarding queries to get the `exams` information